# Zoho CRM Custom Function Deluge Script update a date field with year of different date field

Tags: crm, zoho, custom-function, zoho-deluge

I'm trying to create a custom function in Zoho CRM that takes the invoice record, looks at the subscription time period (start date and end date) and divides the subtotal over the months of the subscription. (April, May, June, etc.) I'm trying to create a date that takes a constant 04/30 and adds the year from the start date year or the end date year, but I'm having trouble with the syntax. I believe there may be something wrong with my if statement as well. Sorry, total noob at this. If anyone could provide a direction on these it would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code I have so far

```
invoice_record = zoho.crm.getRecordById("Invoices", invoice_id);
start_date = invoice_record.get("Service Start Date");
end_date = invoice_record.get("Service End Date");
invoice_date = invoice_record.get("Invoice Date");
start_date_month = start_date.getMonth();
start_date_year = start_date.getyear ();
end_date_year = end_date.getyear();

// calculate how many months in the service period

service_length = start_date.monthsBetween(end_date);

//April Revenue Recognition

april_date_start_year_datestring = "04/30/" + start_date_year;

april_date_start_year = april_date_start_year_datestring.todate( "MM/dd/yyyy") ;

april_date_end_year_datestring = "04/30/" + end_date_year;

april_date_end_year = april_date_end_year_datestring.todate( "mm/dd/yyyy") ;

if (april_date_start_year >= start_date || april_date_end_year < = april_date_end_year ) 
{ rev_rec_april = "Sub Total" / service_length }
else
{rev_rec_april = 0}

invoice_record.put("April Revenue", rev_rec_april);

update_resp = zoho.crm.updateRecord("invoices", invoice_id.toString(), invoice_record);
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone finds this useful later, here is what ended up working:

```
invoice_record = zoho.crm.getRecordById("Invoices",invoice_id);
start_date_datestring = invoice_record.get("Service_Date");
start_date = start_date_datestring.toDate("yyyy-MM-dd");
end_date_datestring = invoice_record.get("End_of_Service_Date");
end_date = end_date_datestring.todate("yyyy-MM-dd");
invoice_date = invoice_record.get("Invoice_Date");
start_date_month = start_date.getMonth();
start_date_year = start_date.getyear();
end_date_year = end_date.getyear();
subtotal2 = invoice_record.get("Sub_Total");
// calculate how many months in the service period
service_length = start_date.monthsBetween(end_date);
//April Revenue Recognition
if(4 >= start_date_month)
{
    april_date_datestring = "04/30/" + start_date_year;
}
else
{
    april_date_datestring = "04/30/" + end_date_year;
}
april_date = april_date_datestring.todate("MM/d/yyyy");
info april_date;
if(april_date >= start_date && april_date <= end_date)
{
    rev_rec_april = (subtotal2 / service_length).round(2);
}
else
{
    rev_rec_april = 0.0;
}
//May Revenue Recognition
if(5 >= start_date_month)
{
    may_date_datestring = "05/31/" + start_date_year;
}
else
{
    may_date_datestring = "05/31/" + end_date_year;
}
may_date = may_date_datestring.todate("MM/d/yyyy");
info may_date;
if(may_date >= start_date && may_date <= end_date)
{
    rev_rec_may = (subtotal2 / service_length).round(2);
}
else
{
    rev_rec_may = 0.0;
}
//June Revenue Recognition
if(6 >= start_date_month)
{
    june_date_datestring = "06/30/" + start_date_year;
}
else
{
    june_date_datestring = "06/30/" + end_date_year;
}
june_date = june_date_datestring.todate("MM/d/yyyy");
info june_date;
if(june_date >= start_date && june_date <= end_date)
{
    rev_rec_june = (subtotal2 / service_length).round(2);
}
else
{
    rev_rec_june = 0.0;
}
//July Revenue
if(7 >= start_date_month)
{
    july_date_datestring = "07/31/" + start_date_year;
}
else
{
    july_date_datestring = "07/31/" + end_date_year;
}
july_date = july_date_datestring.todate("MM/d/yyyy");
info july_date;
if(july_date >= start_date && july_date <= end_date)
{
    rev_rec_july = (subtotal2 / service_length).round(2);
}
else
{
    rev_rec_july = 0.0;
}
//August Revenue
if(8 >= start_date_month)
{
    august_date_datestring = "08/31/" + start_date_year;
}
else
{
    august_date_datestring = "08/31/" + end_date_year;
}
august_date = august_date_datestring.todate("MM/d/yyyy");
info august_date;
if(august_date >= start_date && august_date <= end_date)
{
    rev_rec_august = (subtotal2 / service_length).round(2);
}
else
{
    rev_rec_august = 0.0;
}
//September Revenue
if(9 >= start_date_month)
{
    september_date_datestring = "09/30/" + start_date_year;
}
else
{
    september_date_datestring = "09/30/" + end_date_year;
}
september_date = september_date_datestring.todate("MM/d/yyyy");
info september_date;
if(september_date >= start_date && september_date <= end_date)
{
    rev_rec_september = (subtotal2 / service_length).round(2);
}
else
{
    rev_rec_september = 0.0;
}
//October Revenue
if(10 >= start_date_month)
{
    october_date_datestring = "10/31/" + start_date_year;
}
else
{
    october_date_datestring = "10/31/" + end_date_year;
}
october_date = october_date_datestring.todate("MM/d/yyyy");
info october_date;
if(october_date >= start_date && october_date <= end_date)
{
    rev_rec_october = (subtotal2 / service_length).round(2);
}
else
{
    rev_rec_october = 0.0;
}
//November Revenue
if(11 >= start_date_month)
{
    november_date_datestring = "11/30/" + start_date_year;
}
else
{
    november_date_datestring = "11/30/" + end_date_year;
}
november_date = november_date_datestring.todate("MM/d/yyyy");
info november_date;
if(november_date >= start_date && november_date <= end_date)
{
    rev_rec_november = (subtotal2 / service_length).round(2);
}
else
{
    rev_rec_november = 0.0;
}
//December Revenue
if(12 >= start_date_month)
{
    december_date_datestring = "12/31/" + start_date_year;
}
else
{
    december_date_datestring = "12/31/" + end_date_year;
}
december_date = december_date_datestring.todate("MM/d/yyyy");
info december_date;
if(december_date >= start_date && december_date <= end_date)
{
    rev_rec_december = (subtotal2 / service_length).round(2);
}
else
{
    rev_rec_december = 0.0;
}
// January Revenue
if(1 >= start_date_month)
{
    january_date_datestring = "01/31/" + start_date_year;
}
else
{
    january_date_datestring = "01/31/" + end_date_year;
}
january_date = january_date_datestring.todate("MM/d/yyyy");
info january_date;
if(january_date >= start_date && january_date <= end_date)
{
    rev_rec_january = (subtotal2 / service_length).round(2);
}
else
{
    rev_rec_january = 0.0;
}
//February Revenue
if(2 >= start_date_month)
{
    february_date_datestring = "02/28/" + start_date_year;
}
else
{
    february_date_datestring = "02/28/" + end_date_year;
}
february_date = february_date_datestring.todate("MM/d/yyyy");
info february_date;
if(february_date >= start_date && february_date <= end_date)
{
    rev_rec_february = (subtotal2 / service_length).round(2);
}
else
{
    rev_rec_february = 0.0;
}
// March Revenue
if(3 >= start_date_month)
{
    march_date_datestring = "03/31/" + start_date_year;
}
else
{
    march_date_datestring = "03/31/" + end_date_year;
}
march_date = march_date_datestring.todate("MM/d/yyyy");
info march_date;
if(march_date >= start_date && march_date <= end_date)
{
    rev_rec_march = (subtotal2 / service_length).round(2);
}
else
{
    rev_rec_march = 0.0;
}
//map all revenue fields
mp = {"April_Revenue":rev_rec_april,"June_Revenue":rev_rec_june,"May_Revenue":rev_rec_may,"July_Revenue":rev_rec_july,"August_Revenue":rev_rec_august,"September_Revenue":rev_rec_september,"October_Revenue":rev_rec_october,"November_Revenue":rev_rec_november,"December_Revenue":rev_rec_december,"January_Revenue":rev_rec_january,"February_Revenue":rev_rec_february,"March_Revenue":rev_rec_march};
info mp;
//update the record
update_resp = zoho.crm.updateRecord("Invoices",invoice_id,mp);
info update_resp;
```