# Syntax formula to calculate age in Zoho

Tags: encoding, computer-science, zoho

What formula to use in syntax to calculate age? I want to enter DOB of the patient and want his/ her age in years and months to reflect.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use the below syntax

```
Datecomp(Now(),${Contacts.Date of Birth})/(24*60*365)
```

It will give the result in decimal.

Note: Once you submit/edit the row data in Zoho CRM Contacts, the formulae field will work. Only formulae available in Zoho CRM module field settings can be used. So the age will be shown for example 33.27 years. Whenever the feature to show age in months will be available you can just the edit the existing syntax.
Check the attached screenshot for the result reference.[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the goal correctly it looks like [gabe17](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2374157/gabe17) does something very close to what you are looking and has a detailed example at the link below:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60510617/14250642

It looks like the key maybe be the line `start_date.monthsBetween(end_date)`, which gets the number of months between 2 dates.